# Form value not submitted through checkbox Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

I have a number of check-boxes based on roles of each user with a many-to-may relationship. But when I try to provide these roles, it does not seem to get saved, although the form returns no error. When I try it out in console, `User.find(1).role_ids = 3` it gets saved and returns check-box ticked when viewed on webpage.
I am new to Rails and I need a little help to get past this.

My .html.erb

```
<%= form_for(:user, url: {action: 'update', id: @user.id}) do |f| %>
<tr>
    <% for role in Role.all %>
    <td><%= check_box "user[role_ids][]", role.id, @user.roles.include?(role) %></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <% end %>
</tr>
```

My controller.rb

```
    def edit 
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
      end
    def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Role assigned successfully" 
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @user.id)
    else
      render('edit')
    end
  end
```

My log file:

```
Started GET "/users/edit/11" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 23:42:49 +0530
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`[0m
Processing by UsersController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"11"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 11  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 11 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mRole Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  [1m[36m (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `roles`.id FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles`.`id` = `roles_users`.`role_id` WHERE `roles_users`.`user_id` = 11[0m
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `roles`.id FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles`.`id` = `roles_users`.`role_id` WHERE `roles_users`.`user_id` = 11  [["user_id", 11]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `roles`.id FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles`.`id` = `roles_users`.`role_id` WHERE `roles_users`.`user_id` = 11[0m  [["user_id", 11]]
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `roles`.id FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles`.`id` = `roles_users`.`role_id` WHERE `roles_users`.`user_id` = 11  [["user_id", 11]]
  Rendered users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (66.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 305ms (Views: 243.2ms | ActiveRecord: 21.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/home.self-b60acab5af8d245ed2b3012f77d11d8d207d8eada27756badaf4ef05770d60f6.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 23:42:49 +0530


Started GET "/assets/three_datas.self-b60acab5af8d245ed2b3012f77d11d8d207d8eada27756badaf4ef05770d60f6.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 23:42:49 +0530


Started GET "/assets/threeddata.self-b60acab5af8d245ed2b3012f77d11d8d207d8eada27756badaf4ef05770d60f6.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 23:42:49 +0530


Started GET "/assets/users.self-b60acab5af8d245ed2b3012f77d11d8d207d8eada27756badaf4ef05770d60f6.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 23:42:49 +0530


Started GET "/assets/application.self-517077f606e4f2083e00ef48850c40b9284304d56f4df49218b1d4fc71083e80.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 23:42:49 +0530


Started GET "/javascripts/public.js" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 23:42:49 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/public.js"):
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (12.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (55.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (26.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (55.0ms)


Started POST "/users/update/11" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 23:42:53 +0530
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"B9vvbQhZJe1H4u9T2XQsIHH14ysoe6oHOAnLt5fKwAOMPBheb/IEHk2Bevqe6Q1unoNGo0IAHQt47WhMI2Uybw==", "user"=>{"role_ids"=>["2", "3"]}, "commit"=>"Update Role", "id"=>"11"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 11  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 11 LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameter: role_ids
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/index?id=11
Completed 302 Found in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/users/index?id=11" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 23:42:53 +0530
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"11"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 11  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  ORDER BY users.id ASC
  Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 29.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/javascripts/public.js" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 23:42:53 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/public.js"):
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (40.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (26.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (57.0ms)


Started GET "/users/edit/11" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 23:42:58 +0530
Processing by UsersController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"11"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 11  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 11 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mRole Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `roles`.id FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles`.`id` = `roles_users`.`role_id` WHERE `roles_users`.`user_id` = 11
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `roles`.id FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles`.`id` = `roles_users`.`role_id` WHERE `roles_users`.`user_id` = 11[0m  [["user_id", 11]]
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `roles`.id FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles`.`id` = `roles_users`.`role_id` WHERE `roles_users`.`user_id` = 11  [["user_id", 11]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `roles`.id FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles`.`id` = `roles_users`.`role_id` WHERE `roles_users`.`user_id` = 11[0m  [["user_id", 11]]
  Rendered users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 36ms (Views: 33.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/javascripts/public.js" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 23:42:58 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/public.js"):
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (40.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (26.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (54.0ms)
```

Comment: Please post your log.

Comment: Doesn't look like the right log - you are showing some sort of routing error.  Separately you should read through the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box) for this and let us know where you get stuck after attempting to follow.

Comment: I have gone through the documentation and also viewed RailCasts tutorials, I don't understand what's going wrong or what I am missing.

Comment: Have you declared accepts_nested_attributes_for :role_ids in your user model? What about strong parameters in the controller?

Comment: @Venice No, can you please elaborate?

Comment: When you want to save relationship dependencies through models in one call, you need to declare accepts_nested_attributes_for in your model. This instructs the model to save dependent children when passed in (rather than ignoring, which is what you are experiencing currently). Check out the docs as they provide far more information than what I can type here. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for

Comment: Also, strong parameters may be playing a part in this. I see you have a call to "user_params". Does that method properly include the :user_ids value?

Answer (score 0):

As in Rails 4, the input need to be white-listed. Adding the unpermitted parameter[] as shown in the log file to the respective controller was all that did the trick.
accepts_nested_attributes_for is also required so that the current model accepts the nested attributes of the other model through the current one.